# How do I simulate browser 'select-all' in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt

I've got a GWT application that displays largely text spans.  I'd like to programatically select all of the text currently in the browser window (similar to pressing  from the browser menu).

Can anybody give me a pointer to this?
cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select all function is not available for the entire DOM, however there is a selectAll message for TextBoxBase, so what is commonly used for large quantities of text where you automatically want to do a select all is to put the text inside a TextArea.  If you don't like the look you can remove the borders from the text area and set it to read-only so that it would appear as just plain text.